# How do I get a list of all the duplicate items using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a list of items that likely has some export issues.  I would like to get a list of the duplicate items so I can manually compare them.  When I try to use pandas [duplicated method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), it only returns the first duplicate.  Is there a a way to get all of the duplicates and not just the first one?

A small subsection of my dataset looks like this:

```
ID,ENROLLMENT_DATE,TRAINER_MANAGING,TRAINER_OPERATOR,FIRST_VISIT_DATE
1536D,12-Feb-12,"06DA1B3-Lebanon NH",,15-Feb-12
F15D,18-May-12,"06405B2-Lebanon NH",,25-Jul-12
8096,8-Aug-12,"0643D38-Hanover NH","0643D38-Hanover NH",25-Jun-12
A036,1-Apr-12,"06CB8CF-Hanover NH","06CB8CF-Hanover NH",9-Aug-12
8944,19-Feb-12,"06D26AD-Hanover NH",,4-Feb-12
1004E,8-Jun-12,"06388B2-Lebanon NH",,24-Dec-11
11795,3-Jul-12,"0649597-White River VT","0649597-White River VT",30-Mar-12
30D7,11-Nov-12,"06D95A3-Hanover NH","06D95A3-Hanover NH",30-Nov-11
3AE2,21-Feb-12,"06405B2-Lebanon NH",,26-Oct-12
B0FE,17-Feb-12,"06D1B9D-Hartland VT",,16-Feb-12
127A1,11-Dec-11,"064456E-Hanover NH","064456E-Hanover NH",11-Nov-12
161FF,20-Feb-12,"0643D38-Hanover NH","0643D38-Hanover NH",3-Jul-12
A036,30-Nov-11,"063B208-Randolph VT","063B208-Randolph VT",
475B,25-Sep-12,"06D26AD-Hanover NH",,5-Nov-12
151A3,7-Mar-12,"06388B2-Lebanon NH",,16-Nov-12
CA62,3-Jan-12,,,
D31B,18-Dec-11,"06405B2-Lebanon NH",,9-Jan-12
20F5,8-Jul-12,"0669C50-Randolph VT",,3-Feb-12
8096,19-Dec-11,"0649597-White River VT","0649597-White River VT",9-Apr-12
14E48,1-Aug-12,"06D3206-Hanover NH",,
177F8,20-Aug-12,"063B208-Randolph VT","063B208-Randolph VT",5-May-12
553E,11-Oct-12,"06D95A3-Hanover NH","06D95A3-Hanover NH",8-Mar-12
12D5F,18-Jul-12,"0649597-White River VT","0649597-White River VT",2-Nov-12
C6DC,13-Apr-12,"06388B2-Lebanon NH",,
11795,27-Feb-12,"0643D38-Hanover NH","0643D38-Hanover NH",19-Jun-12
17B43,11-Aug-12,,,22-Oct-12
A036,11-Aug-12,"06D3206-Hanover NH",,19-Jun-12
```

My code looks like this currently:

```
df_bigdata_duplicates = df_bigdata[df_bigdata.duplicated(cols='ID')]
```

There area a couple duplicate items. But, when I use the above code, I only get the first item.  In the API reference, I see how I can get the last item, but I would like to have all of them so I can visually inspect them to see why I am getting the discrepancy.  So, in this example I would like to get all three A036 entries and both 11795 entries and any other duplicated entries, instead of the just first one.  Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: "Duplicates" can mean various things" In your case, you only want to consider **duplicates in a single column `ID`**, not "rows identical in multiple or all columns".

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Method #1: print all rows where the ID is one of the IDs in duplicated:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("dup.csv")
>>> ids = df["ID"]
>>> df[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])].sort_values("ID")
       ID ENROLLMENT_DATE        TRAINER_MANAGING        TRAINER_OPERATOR FIRST_VISIT_DATE
24  11795       27-Feb-12      0643D38-Hanover NH      0643D38-Hanover NH        19-Jun-12
6   11795        3-Jul-12  0649597-White River VT  0649597-White River VT        30-Mar-12
18   8096       19-Dec-11  0649597-White River VT  0649597-White River VT         9-Apr-12
2    8096        8-Aug-12      0643D38-Hanover NH      0643D38-Hanover NH        25-Jun-12
12   A036       30-Nov-11     063B208-Randolph VT     063B208-Randolph VT              NaN
3    A036        1-Apr-12      06CB8CF-Hanover NH      06CB8CF-Hanover NH         9-Aug-12
26   A036       11-Aug-12      06D3206-Hanover NH                     NaN        19-Jun-12
```

but I couldn't think of a nice way to prevent repeating `ids` so many times.  I prefer method #2: `groupby` on the ID.

```
>>> pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("ID") if len(g) > 1)
       ID ENROLLMENT_DATE        TRAINER_MANAGING        TRAINER_OPERATOR FIRST_VISIT_DATE
6   11795        3-Jul-12  0649597-White River VT  0649597-White River VT        30-Mar-12
24  11795       27-Feb-12      0643D38-Hanover NH      0643D38-Hanover NH        19-Jun-12
2    8096        8-Aug-12      0643D38-Hanover NH      0643D38-Hanover NH        25-Jun-12
18   8096       19-Dec-11  0649597-White River VT  0649597-White River VT         9-Apr-12
3    A036        1-Apr-12      06CB8CF-Hanover NH      06CB8CF-Hanover NH         9-Aug-12
12   A036       30-Nov-11     063B208-Randolph VT     063B208-Randolph VT              NaN
26   A036       11-Aug-12      06D3206-Hanover NH                     NaN        19-Jun-12
```

Comment: Method #2 fails ("No objects to concatenate") if there are no dups

Comment: what does `g for _`  do?

Comment: @user77005 you might've figured out already, but for everyone's benefit, it reads like this: `g for (placeholder, g) in df.groupby('bla') if 'bla'`; the underscore is a typical symbol for placeholder of an inevitable argument where we don't want to use it for anything in a lambda-like expression.

Comment: Method #1 needs to be updated: `sort` was deprecated for DataFrames in favor of either `sort_values` or `sort_index` [Related SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123874/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-sort)

Comment: I have tried this and the snippets provided in this thread, **they all return different results**. Can anyone share which is more appropriate to use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909119/to-sort-group-and-display-duplicated-values-of-a-column

Comment: method 2 is great for small datasets, but very quickly the memory explodes on bigger dataframes.

Comment: Im trying to group by customer_id, product_id and price and get an error when running the below 
pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("customer_id", "product_id", "price") if len(g) > 1)

Comment: method 2 is way slower than method 1

Answer (score 271):

With Pandas version 0.17, you can set 'keep = False' in the [duplicated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) function to get all the duplicate items.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d','a','b'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
       0
    0  a
    1  b
    2  c
    3  d
    4  a
    5  b

In [4]: df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[4]: 
       0
    0  a
    1  b
    4  a
    5  b
```

Comment: Bingo, there's the answer. So: str or str or boolean... odd API choice. `'all'` would be more logical and intuitive IMO.

Comment: @Jarad You don't find it to be intuitive that `keep=False` means, "yes, keep everything"? Strange. /s

Answer (score 261):

```
df[df.duplicated(['ID'], keep=False)]
```

it'll return all duplicated rows back to you.

According to [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

> `keep` : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
>
> - 'first' : Mark duplicates as True except for the first occurrence.
> - 'last' : Mark duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.
> - False : Mark all duplicates as True.

Answer (score 28):

*As I am unable to comment, hence posting as a separate answer*

To find duplicates on the basis of more than one column, mention every column name
as below, and it will return you all the duplicated rows set:

```
df[df[['product_uid', 'product_title', 'user']].duplicated() == True]
```

Alternatively,

```
df[df[['product_uid', 'product_title', 'user']].duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 18):

```
df[df['ID'].duplicated() == True]
```

This worked for me

Comment: You actually do not have to add `== True`, `.duplicated()` already returns bool array.

Answer (score 6):

`sort("ID")` does not seem to be working now, seems deprecated as per [sort doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html), so use `sort_values("ID")` instead to sort after duplicate filter, as following:

```
df[df.ID.duplicated(keep=False)].sort_values("ID")
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
df[df.duplicated(['ID'])==True].sort_values('ID')
```

duplicated rows and their index loc # for all column values

```
def dup_rows_index(df):
  dup = df[df.duplicated()]
  print('Duplicated index loc:',dup[dup == True ].index.tolist())
  return dup
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution! It would be kind if you could extend you answer by an explanation. Here you find a guide [How to give a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using an element-wise logical or and setting the take_last argument of the pandas duplicated method to both True and False you can obtain a set from your dataframe that includes all of the duplicates.

```
df_bigdata_duplicates = 
    df_bigdata[df_bigdata.duplicated(cols='ID', take_last=False) |
               df_bigdata.duplicated(cols='ID', take_last=True)
              ]
```

Answer (score 4):

This may not be a solution to the question, but to illustrate examples:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,1,3,4],
    'B': [2,2,5,6],
    'C': [3,4,7,6],
})

print(df)
df.duplicated(keep=False)
df.duplicated(['A','B'], keep=False)
```

The outputs:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
2  3  5  7
3  4  6  6

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 4):

For my database `.duplicated(keep=False)` did not work until the column was sorted.

```
data.sort_values(by=['Order ID'], inplace=True)
df = data[data['Order ID'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This code gives you a data frame indicating if a row has any repetition in the data frame:

```
df2 = df1.duplicated()
```

This code eliminates the duplications and keeps only one instance:

```
df3 = df1.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
```

`df3` will be a data frame consisting from the unique items (rows).

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR

This worked for me:

```py
dups = [i for i, v in df["Col1"].value_counts().iteritems() if v > 1]
dups
```

Output:

```
[501, 505]
```

To list duplicate rows:

```
fltr = df["Col1"].isin(dups)  # Filter
df[fltr]
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2
0   501     D
1   501     H
2   505     E
3   501     E
4   505     M
```

##### Explanation:

Taking `value_counts()` of a column, say *Col1*, returns a `Series` with:

1. Data of column `Col1` as the `Series` index.
2. Count of values in `Col1` as the `Series` values.

For example `value_counts()` on below `DataFrame`:

|  | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 501 | D |
| 1 | 501 | H |
| 2 | 505 | E |
| 3 | 501 | E |
| 4 | 505 | M |
| 5 | 502 | A |
| 6 | 503 | N |

```
df["Col1"].value_counts()
```

Outputs below `Series`:

```
501    3
505    2
502    1
503    1
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
```

Now using `iteritems()` we can access both index and values of a `Series` object:

```py
dups = [i for i, v in df["Col1"].value_counts().iteritems() if v > 1]
dups
```

Output:

```
[501, 505]
```

Now use the duplicate values captured as filter on original `DataFrame`.

```
fltr = df["Col1"].isin(dups)  # Filter
df[fltr]
```

```
   Col1  Col2
0   501     D
1   501     H
2   505     E
3   501     E
4   505     M
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the solutions above, you can further sort values so that you can look at the records that are duplicated sorted:

```
df[df.duplicated(['ID'], keep=False)].sort_values(by='ID')
```