# Pandas duplicated vs groupby to flag all duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pretty simple need that has come up in a couple other posts, but I'm not sure if a better way to approach it is with a `groupby` or `duplicated` method.

I have what I need below with `duplicated` *except* the first duplicate is being flagged as `FALSE` instead of `TRUE`. I need all duplicates as TRUE.

My goal is to be able to concatenate data from two columns together when it's a duplicate, otherwise, leave the data as-is.

Sample Input:

```
ID  File Name
1   Text.csv
2   TEXT.csv
3   unique.csv
4   unique2.csv
5   text.csv
```

Desired Output:

```
ID  File Name   LowerFileName   Duplicate   UniqueFileName
1   Text.csv    text.csv    TRUE    1Text.csv
2   TEXT.csv    text.csv    TRUE    2TEXT.csv
3   unique.csv  unique.csv  FALSE   unique.csv
4   unique2.csv unique2.csv FALSE   unique2.csv
5   text.csv    text.csv    TRUE    5text.csv


df_attachment = pd.read_csv("Attachment.csv")
df_attachment['LowerFileName'] = df_attachment['File Name'].str.lower()
df_attachment['Duplicate'] = df_attachment.duplicated('LowerFileName')
#This syntax is incorrect 
df_attachment['UniqueFileName'] = np.where(df_attachment['Duplicate']=='TRUE', pd.concat(df_attachment['ID'],df_attachment['File Name']), df_attachment['File Name'))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the LowerFileName in the desired output for ID 4 be 'unique2.csv'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the use of `groupby` together with a `lambda` expression can achieve your objective:

```
gb = df.groupby('Lower File Name')['Lower File Name'].count()
duplicates = gb[gb > 1].index.tolist()
df['UniqueFileName'] = \
    df.apply(lambda x: '{0}{1}'.format(x.ID if x['Lower File Name'] in duplicates
                                       else "", x['File Name']), axis=1)

>>> df
   ID    File Name Lower File Name Duplicate   UniqueFileName
0   1     Text.csv        text.csv     False        1Text.csv
1   2     TEXT.csv        text.csv      True        2TEXT.csv
2   3   unique.csv      unique.csv     False      3unique.csv
3   4  unique2.csv     unique2.csv     False  Noneunique2.csv
4   5     text.csv        text.csv      True        5text.csv
5   6   uniquE.csv      unique.csv      True      6uniquE.csv
```

The lambda expression generates a unique filename per the OP's requirements by prepending `File Name` with the relevant `ID` only in the event that the `Lower File Name` is duplicated (i.e. there is more than one file with the same lower case file name).  Otherwise, it just uses the lowercase filename without an `ID`.

Note that this solution does not use the `Duplicate` column in the above DataFrame.

Also, wouldn't it be simpler to simply append the `ID` to the `Lower File Name` in order to generate a unique name?  You wouldn't need the solution above and don't even need to check for duplicates, assuming the ID is unique.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! I had to make one modification as it was appending "None" to the non-duplicate file names:  `df.apply(lambda x: '{0}{1}'.format(x.ID if x['Lower File Name'] in duplicates                                        else '', x['File Name']), axis=1)`  And yes, it would have been much easier to just append the ID in all cases but unfortunately had to match another file in that format.

Comment: This is a bit tricky from a readability perspective. It's a bit hard to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to "get around" this odd Pandas functionality is to generate a mask using `df.duplicated(col_name) | df.duplicated(col_name, take_last=True)`. The bitwise or means that the series you generate is `True` for all duplicates.

Follow this with using the indexes to set the values that you from the original name or a new name with the number in fron.

In your case below:

```
# Generating your DataFrame
df_attachment = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5))
df_attachment['ID'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
df_attachment['File Name'] = ['Text.csv', 'TEXT.csv', 'unique.csv',
                             'unique2.csv', 'text.csv']
df_attachment['LowerFileName'] = df_attachment['File Name'].str.lower()


# Answer from here, mask generation over two lines for readability
mask = df_attachment.duplicated('LowerFileName')
mask = mask | df_attachment.duplicated('LowerFileName', take_last=True)
df_attachment['Duplicate'] = mask

# New column names if possible
df_attachment['number_name'] = df_attachment['ID'].astype(str) + df_attachment['File Name']

# Set the final unique name column using the mask already generated
df_attachment.loc[mask, 'UniqueFileName'] = df_attachment.loc[mask, 'number_name']
df_attachment.loc[~mask, 'UniqueFileName'] = df_attachment.loc[~mask, 'File Name']

# Drop the intermediate column used
del df_attachment['number_name']
```

And the final `df_attachment`:

```
    ID  File Name   LowerFileName   Duplicate   UniqueFileName
0   1   Text.csv    text.csv    True    1Text.csv
1   2   TEXT.csv    text.csv    True    2TEXT.csv
2   3   unique.csv  unique.csv  False   unique.csv
3   4   unique2.csv unique2.csv False   unique2.csv
4   5   text.csv    text.csv    True    5text.csv
```

This method uses vectorised pandas operations and indexing so should be quick for any size DataFrame.

### EDIT: 2017-03-28

Someone gave this a vote yesterday so I thought I would edit this to say that this has been supported natively by pandas since `0.17.0`, see the changes here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/whatsnew.html#v0-17-0-october-9-2015

Now you can use the `keep` argument of `drop_duplicates` and `duplicated` and set it to `False` to mark all duplicates: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

So above the lines generating duplicated column become:

`df_attachment['Duplicate'] = df_attachment.duplicated('LowerFileName', keep=False)`

Answer (score 1):

For your use case you'll need to use groupby:

```
dupes = df_attachment.groupby('Name').ID.count() > 1
dupes.name = 'Duplicate'
#merge duplicate flage into the original dataframe on the common column 'Name'
df_attachment = pd.merge(df_attachment, dupes.reset_index())
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14657511/2071807) you could do (assuming your `File Name` column is renamed to `file_name`):

```
df['unique_name'] = df.file_name
dupes = df.file_name[df.file_name.str.lower().duplicated()]
unique_names = df.ID.astype(str) + df.file_name
df.loc[df.file_name.isin(dupes), 'unique_name'] = unique_names
```

Which gives you:

```
   ID    File Name  unique_name
0   1     Text.csv     Text.csv
1   2     TEXT.csv    2TEXT.csv
2   3   unique.csv   unique.csv
3   4  unique2.csv  unique2.csv
4   5     text.csv    5text.csv
```