# How to find duplicates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I've a data frame of about 52000 rows with some duplicates, when I use

```
df_drop_duplicates()
```

I loose about 1000 rows, but I don't want to erase this rows I want to know which ones are the duplicates rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of all the duplicate items using pandas in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-duplicate-items-using-pandas-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for that:

```
df[df.duplicated()]
```

You could specify `keep` argument for what you want, from [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

> ***keep** : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’*
>
> - `first` : Mark duplicates as `True` except for the first occurrence.
> - `last` : Mark duplicates as `True` except for the last occurrence.
> - `False` : Mark all duplicates as `True`.

Answer (score 0):

To identify duplicates within a pandas column without dropping the duplicates, try:

Let
'Column_A' = column with duplicate entries
'Column_B' = a true/false column that marks duplicates in Column A.

```
df['Column_B'] = df.duplicated(subset='Column_A', keep='first')
```

Change the parameters to fine tune to your needs.