# Retain only duplicated rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with two columns: "Agent" and "Client"
Each row corresponds to an interaction between an Agent and a client.

I want to keep only the rows if a client had interactions with at least 2 agents.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should use group by in pandas to do this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of all the duplicate items using pandas in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-duplicate-items-using-pandas-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `transform` by `value_counts`.

```
df[df.Agent.groupby(df.Agent).transform('value_counts') > 1]
```

Note, that, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263846/keep-only-rows-with-duplicates/46263872?noredirect=1#comment79490894_46263872), you might have one agent interacting with the same client multiple times. This might be retained as a false positive. If you do not want this, you could add a `drop_duplicates` call before filtering:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = df[df.Agent.groupby(df.Agent).transform('value_counts') > 1]
```

---

```
print(df)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  5
2  3  1
3  4  1
4  5  5
5  6  1

mask = df.B.groupby(df.B).transform('value_counts') > 1
print(mask)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: B, dtype: bool

df = df[mask]
print(df)
   A  B
1  2  5
2  3  1
3  4  1
4  5  5
5  6  1
```

Comment: The OP doesn't mention it, but might want to cater for the case where there's repeated interactions with a single agent which would currently be considered (possibly incorrectly)... Might want to throw in `.drop_duplicates()` before grouping...

Comment: @JonClements Sure, sounds reasonable. Added in.

Answer (score 9):

Worth adding that now you can use `df.duplicated()`

```py
df = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset='Agent', keep=False)]
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!