# how to check if there a duplicate record in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check if there is a duplicate record for all the columns in a DataFrame and to drop that record.

I am trying something like this but I am not sure if this is the right approach.

`#remove duplicates 
repair = repair.drop_duplicates(subset=None,keep="first")`

Comment: does it work? does it fail? what do you get?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Any other questions...? You could've just looked at your output to see if it was doing what you wanted.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-duplicate-items-using-pandas-in-python

Comment: sorry the solution I provided works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repair = repair.drop_duplicates(subset=None,keep="first")`

This helps to remove all duplicate records