# to sort, group and display duplicated values of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, group-by

I would like to sort, group and display duplicated values of a column in table form. I found some code snippets [from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-duplicate-items-using-pandas-in-python). However, they produced different output. Which is a better way and what are the difference between them?

```
pd.concat(g for _, g in df.groupby("column_name") if len(g) > 1)
```

The above show values with special characters but doesn't show NaN

```
>>> ids = df["column_name"]
>>> df[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])].sort_values("column_name")
```

The above shows NaN but not special characters.

```
df[df['column_name'].duplicated() == True]
```

Completely different results from the above two.

Comment: You should probably add the output as well

Comment: Can you give some example input data? Which kind of special characters? Are you working in utf-8 and using accents etc?

Comment: I went for both ways and got the same result with my dataset: indices = ints; testcontent = "abc_123456" with random letters and numbers