# How to get a list of first duplicate value in column in csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I need to find all the duplicates in one column of a csv file, and then export these to a different csv file. I've tried answers from this:[How do I get a list of all the duplicate items using pandas in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-duplicate-items-using-pandas-in-python) but am not getting the correct result.
Example of my csv file:

```
    filename,ID,status
    71.wav,107e,accepted
    85.wav,9a99,accepted
    85.wav,d27a,accepted
    86.wav,ea4f,accepted
    86.wav,9f9b,accepted
    75.wav,b734,accepted
    75.wav,3dfb,accepted
```

I would like an output of:

```
    85.wav,9a99,accepted
    86.wav,ea4f,accepted
    75.wav,b734,accepted
```

I tried:

```
    ids = df["filename"]
    dups = df[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])].sort_values("filename")
    print dups
```

The output of this gave unique values as well as duplicate values.

My expected output would be a csv file with the first duplicate listed as shown above (I edited the question to clarify).

Comment: `df[df.duplicated('filename')]` ? for keeping all dupe values , `df[df.duplicated('filename',keep=False)]` ?

Comment: But how to extract the duplicates only so I can work with them?

Comment: thanks i've edited the question now so it's clearer and includes an expected output.

Comment: did you try my comments above?addimg `last` to the same resolves it  `df[df.duplicated('filename',keep='last')].to_csv(.....)` ?

Comment: yes i tried the one above and the output csv had the same number of rows as the original.

Comment: well `df[df.duplicated('filename',keep='last')]` gives me exactly what you have shown as expected output , if not then probably you have unwanted spaces in your original data and you might want to `strip()` them off

Comment: totally right, I did have issues in original data, removed those, and this works great. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5],
                   "name":["Georgia","Georgia","Georgia","Georgia","Camila","Camila","Diego","Luis","Jose"]})


duplicates = df[df.duplicated(["id"])]
```

Returns

```
   id     name
1   1  Georgia
2   1  Georgia
3   1  Georgia
5   2   Camila
```

Comment: i edited my question now so you can see expected result.

Comment: So you want to keep last? Try this ```duplicates = df[df.duplicated(["id"],keep = "last")]```

Answer (score 0):

This method should definitively help.

```
data = {'Test':[1,2,3,4,5,6,2,4,2,5,6,3,2,7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

dups = df[df.duplicated()]
```

returns

Test
6   2
7   4
8   2
9   5
10  6
11  3
12  2