# Count the number of duplicates in a column and list them out

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to count the number of duplicated IP address in my column and list them out. What i have so far is:

```
authorized = df_log[df_log['Access Type'] == 'Authorized']
authorized = authorized.groupby('host/IP address')\
.size().reset_index(name='No. of times Duplicated')
```

The problem with this is that it displays the counts of all the IP addresses even those that appear just once for example:

[image]

So I'm trying to filter out where size > 1 I guess. Also, the number of times duplicated should be 1 less for each number. The output i want is similar to the picture except number 21 is gone and all the numbers are reduced by 1

Comment: You filter using `authorized = authorized-1` considering it is a series and then `authorized = authorized.loc[authorized.ne(0), :]`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this

Comment: The output authorized is reduced by 1 using the first highlighted code and then we are filtering the values that are not equal to 0.

Comment: Is this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14657241/12744275

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
ips = authorized['host/IP address']
# select duplicated IPS
duplicated_ips = ips[ips.duplicated()]
# count them
counts_duplicated_ips = duplicated_ips.value_counts()
```

P.S. Thanks @tidakdiinginkan in the comments.

Comment: I'd say this - [pandas.DataFrame.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) would be better.

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan right, but he needs the counts, so probably the best is to combine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['dups'] = df['IP'].duplicated()
print(df[df['dups']==True].groupby(by=['Access']).count())
```