# How do I check if a value is appearing multiple times in the same column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

for i and x in df1.total_amount:
if i in df1['total_amount'] == x in df1['total_amount']:
    print( str(i) + " is repeating")
```

This does not return the desired result.

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether your column has repeated values? Or are you having a specific value and want to check if it's found multiple times in the column?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41786821) answer.

Comment: i am  trying to determine whether my column has repeated values