# More pythonic way to remove rows where one value begins by another row's value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing a pandas dataframe and want to remove rows if they contain a "Full Path" that is already contained in other "Full Path" of the dataframe.

In the example below I want to remove the rows 1 2 3 4 because c:/dir/ "contains" them (we are talking about file systems path here):

```
     Full Path        Value
0    c:/dir/            x
1    c:/dir/sub1/       x
2    c:/dir/sub2/       x
3    c:/dir/sub2/a      x
4    c:/dir/sub2/b      x
5    c:/anotherdir/     x
6    c:/anotherdir_A/   x
7    c:/anotherdir_C/   x
```

Rows 6 & 7 are kept because the path is not contained in 5 (`a in b` in my code below).

The code I came up with is the following, res is the initial dataframe:

```
to_drop = []
for index, row in res.iterrows():
    a = row['Full Path']
    for idx, row2 in res.iterrows():
        b = row2['Full Path']
        if a != b and a in b:
            to_drop.append(idx)
res2 = res.loc[~res.index.isin(to_drop)]
```

It works but the code does not feel 100% pythonic to me. I am quite sure there is a more elegant/clever way to do this. Any idea?

Comment: Are you only considering subdirectories as "contained", or should rows containing `c:/dira` and `c:/dirb` also be considered as duplicates?

Comment: no they are different directories, not dup in my case (the a in b test is enough for me it's the double loop that seems clumsy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of all the duplicate items using pandas in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241)

Comment: @Trenton McKinney It would if I could define what a duplicate is (in my case it's "a in b and a != b")

Answer (score 2):

```
pd.concat([df, df['Full Path'].str.extract('(.*:\/.*?\/)')], axis = 1)\
  .drop_duplicates([0])\
  .drop(columns = 0)
```

You can use `.str.extract` and regex to extract the base directory, concating the extract back to the original df, dropping the duplicates of the base directory, followed by finally dropping the extracted column.

Edit: Alternate if Path is not in order:

```
df[df['Full Path'] == df['Full Path'].str.extract('(.*:\/.*?\/)', expand = False)]
```

Comment: If the dataframe is not sorted by `Full Path` this will not always provide the correct output (assuming OP wants to always get the top-most-not-duplicated entry)

Comment: Thats a good point. In that case you can use the extraction as a filter to match against the Path column. See my edit. This is probably better than my original answer.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of this is in the tank (no matter how you turn it, you have to check every path against every other path), but a single line solution using `str.startswith`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Full Path': ['c:/dir/', 'c:/dir/sub/', 'c:/anotherdir/dir',
                                 'c:/anotherdir/'],
                   'Value': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})

print(df[[any(a.startswith(b) if a != b else False for a in df['Full Path'])
          for b in df['Full Path']]])
```

output

```
        Full Path Value
0         c:/dir/     A
3  c:/anotherdir/     D
```