# How to remove duplicate values in a column but keep unique values corresponding to other columns in one row?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have the following dataframe

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to remove the duplicates in ID column and keep all the values corresponding to other columns in one row as shown below

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I used iterrows but didn't get the required result. Please help me with python code.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J22k.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZKYc.png

Comment: The link to your images were not inserted properly

Comment: Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [Not Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop all duplicate rows across multiple columns in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667369/drop-all-duplicate-rows-across-multiple-columns-in-python-pandas)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of all the duplicate items using pandas in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy()))
```

Output:

```
   1st Month Sales  2nd Month Sales  3rd Month Sales
0           2500.0           3450.0           1349.0
1              NaN           1200.0           2300.0
```