# How to extract all duplicated rows from dataframe and delete them from dataframe in pysapark,pandas

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

[image]

On basis of column Articlenbr and amount need to check duplicates and extract those duplicates in another dataframe. Ex in below example i want to extract 1st two rows ,save it in another dataframe and delete from original dataframe. How can be done in pyspark.

Duplicated rows(save in another dataframe):
[image]

original dataframe :
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove pandas rows with duplicate indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-pandas-rows-with-duplicate-indices). or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657241/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-duplicate-items-using-pandas-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dups = df.groupby('Articlenbr').count()
dups = dups[dups['amount']>1].index.values
df[df['Articlenbr'].isin(dups)]
```